# How to export image without showing it in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, export, png

I have probelm with code below (it's simplified test version):

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class Example {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel background;
    JPanel top;
    JPanel center;
    JPanel bottom;

    public Example() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1016, 639);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        background = new JPanel();
        background.setLayout(new BoxLayout(background, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        background.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));

        top = new JPanel();
        top.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 200));
        top.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        center = new JPanel();
        center.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 200));
        center.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 200));
        bottom.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        background.add(top);
        background.add(center);
        background.add(bottom);

        frame.add(background);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


   public void getImage() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1000, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        background.paint(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("frame_2.png"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.getImage();
    }
 }
```

All I want to do is to export JPanel *background* as png file without showing the frame. Problem is, that now it works, but if I comment line:

`frame.setVisible(true);`

all I get is png file all black, with the right size.

I thing components are not properly painted if setVisible is false, I looked on the internet, but with my short experience with swing I found nothing that works. Maybe someone here could help?

**SOLUTION**

Use functions pack() to create components with sizes and dispose() to finish swing's loop.

```
public void getImage() {
    frame.pack();
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1000, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    background.paint(g2d);
    g2d.dispose();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("frame_2.png"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know why setVisible(true) show your png as expected and when false it makes all black??

Comment: Not exactly - when I have setVisible(true) I see the whole frame, I export background JPanel using getImage() method, and frame_2.png file is created, and I have there the same image I have in my JFrame (three rectangles - black, white and blue). I don't want JFrame to show up, but I sitll want to have this png file with JFrame's content. Right now, if I add setVisible(false), the png file is created, but is wole black.

Comment: Do you just want to create some image and save it? Or do you want to save a screen capture of your _Swing_ GUI without needing to display it on the screen first?

Comment: Yes, in short I want to save a screen capture of my Swing GUI without needing to display it on the screen first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing components don't have a size until you pack() the frame or invoke setVisible( true ) on the frame, since the layout manager hasn't been invoked.

So try invoking pack() before you invoke the getImage() method.

You can also try using  [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) which is a reusable class that allows you to create an image of the desktop, frame or any component on the frame. It will automatically handle setting the size of the components even if they are not yet visible on the frame.

Comment: Adding frame.pack() before  background.paint(g2d); makes the program never end, so there must be some endless loop inside, but thanks for reply, I will try Screen Image.

Comment: Once you start a Swing application the Event Dispatch Thread is started. The EDT is waiting for user events. Since you never made the frame visible you don't see the frame which would allow you to close it. So, instead you should be able to add a `frame.dispose()` after you invoke the getImage() method. This will close the frame and allow the EDT to terminate.